# Check if a website is in a certain language and if so, block it

Tags: javascript, userscript

I try to block all websites in Hebrew because I want to give more time on websites in other languages.

Given that many webmasters don't add `<meta name="language" content="Hebrew">` meta attribute to all webpages of their websites I can't use it to block websites which appear in a certain language.

According to one work [the most common letter in Hebrew](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%97%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%AA) is *Yod* (`'`), parallel to the Arabic *Ya* (`ي`) and common in all Semitic languages, so what I try to do is to just block any webpage that has *Yod* in it:

```js
const [...elements] = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
elements.forEach((element) => {
  if (element.textContent.includes("י")) {
      window.open("https://google.com/", "_self");
  }
});
```

In my tests the code works on Hebrew-appearing-websites and doesn't work on non-Hebrew-appearing-websites, but maybe there is something to improve?

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. If you think there is anything to improve please comment or suggest an edit (which I will gladly examine ASAP).

Comment: What prompted you to write this and what does the rest of the program look like?

Comment: @Mast I don't understand the first clarification question ; that's all my code in this context, there is no other code.

Comment: @Mast I have edited; is that better?

Answer (score 1):

Your script will only work correctly if it is placed after the Yod character. Consider adding an event listener for `window.load` to only call it when all the content is loaded:

```javascript
addEventListener("load", () => {
    ...
});
```

There is no need to iterate through all the elements. You could have simply used `document.documentElement.innerHTML`. The only problem with this is that it will find the character in the script itself. To fix this we can use `String.fromCharCode`:

```javascript
if (document.documentElement.innerHTML.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(1497)) >= 0)
    document.location = 'https://he.wikipedia.org/';
```

Comment: Using `window.onload` does not guarantee it will be call as it can easily be over written by other code/extensions,  Always use `addEventListener` to add listeners to ensure that they are called. `window` is the default `this`, it use is redundant (ie you don't use for  `window.document`) thus  `window.onload = function () {` becomes `addEventListener("load", () => {`

Comment: @Blindman67, thanks. jQuery has made me stupid =)